# Is it possible to click on link available in email using flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

Wanted to click on a link from Gmail that is sent to the user's email address from the app. Is it possible to achieve this using Flutter integration tests? If yes, can someone help with the steps using Flutter integration tests?

I am trying to click on a link from Gmail, and then it should navigate to the respective app and proceed with further steps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.